# When to use Handler/Message to communicate in android application

Tags: android

I can use Intent with data stored in extras to exchange information/ communicate between 2 android activities. When should I use  Handler/Message to communicate in android applications?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlers are tied to threads, so you'd use handler when you want a task to run in another (typically UI) thread.